# do_shortcode for is_page(slug)

Tags: shortcode

iam new with php and wordpress. i try to implement a shortcode which should only work for a specific slug for my website. all other sites should do another shortcode.

i tryed this:

```
<?php
if( is_page( ( 'azubi');
     <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="274"       title="Bewerbungsformular_beruf" ]' ); ?> 
else
     <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="2741"     title="Bewerbungsformular_berufe" ]' ); ?> 

 <?phpendif ?>
```

but with this i got an error. i thin php syntax is wrong? works this solution for that i want to have?

best regards
tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line `if( is_page( ( 'azubi');` you start but not end the round bracket ["(" OR ")"] and not used semicolon after the if condition used colon like  `if( is_page('azubi')):`

```
<?php
if( is_page('azubi')):
     echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="274" title="Bewerbungsformular_beruf" ]' ); 
else:
     echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="2741" title="Bewerbungsformular_berufe" ]' ); 

endif; 
?>
```

Check this : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

Enter correct page name.

```
     if( is_page('About Us')):
                 echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="263" title="Contact form 1"]');
            else:
                 echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="264" title="Contact form 1_copy"]');

            endif;
```

Comment: thanks! no there is no php error anymore. but the code is not doing what he should. on all pages there is still the same contactform. but on the page /karriere/azubi there should be another one. Can you help me?

Comment: I think you can wrong page title enter in is_page() because this code run in my setup. please check the updated answer.

Comment: it works! thanks! i was in a custom post type and thatswhy i have to use is_single , thanks!